# Train accuracy much higher than test accuracy

Tags: python, image-processing, deep-learning, classification, multiclass-classification

I have a problem.
I have a dataset of 20047 images with labels. My goal is classification (8 classes).
I'm using EfficientNet pretrain on imagenet. I changed the last layer.
I'm using 10-fold cross validation and the generator to load the images.

```
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
    dataframe=train_df,
    directory=train_dir,
    x_col="img",
    y_col="label",
    target_size=(224, 224),
    batch_size=16,
    class_mode='sparse')

test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
    dataframe=test_df,
    directory=test_dir,
    x_col="img",
    y_col="label",
    target_size=(224, 224),
    batch_size=16,
    class_mode='sparse')

epochs=15
batch_size=16
history=model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=(18042/batch_size),
    epochs=epochs)
```

During training I get accuracy >=0.86 and loss<=0.88, but when I predict labels on test dataset I get an accuracy very low, around 0.18.

Other info:
(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=False)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: There isn't enough information to really give an answer, but it sounds like you're overfitting your training data. As a starting point, you can try some standard things: reduce model complexity (e.g. number of params), add regularization and also stop training a bit early.

Comment: Sorry @hrokr, how can I prevent this difference between train accuracy and test accuracy?

Comment: @Ash I tried with bigger batch size and less epochs but the results was the same or similar. Now I will try with regularization.

Comment: Do data augmentation can be a possible solution? Take augmented data to train the model and then test it on original data.

I'm trying with dropout but perfomance during test step drops drastically.